# Handle swing ScrollBar events in scala

Tags: swing, scala

I am trying to add a `ScrollBar`.  The `ScrollBar` will iterate through the documents displayed.  However, I am having trouble receiving an event when the scroll bar changes.  I'm not sure what I need to listen to, and I'm not sure what event I should be responding to.  I tried the following and I get some events, but I don't think these are the ideal events to handle.

```
  listenTo(scrollBar)
  listenTo(scrollBar.keys)
  listenTo(scrollBar.mouse.moves)
  listenTo(scrollBar.mouse.wheel)
  listenTo(scrollBar.mouse.clicks)
```

For example, I only get `MouseClicked`, `MousePressed`, and `MouseReleased` when I click inside the scrollbar--not when I click on the arrows to actually change the value.

I found [this discussion](http://scala-programming-language.1934581.n4.nabble.com/ScrollBar-events-not-received-td1951980.html) about scroll bars not receiving events properly, but it's two years old.  As far as I can tell, the author did not follow up an file a ticket.  Maybe he found a workaround.

Any ideas?

Comment: can you upload the whole code? and you can not add scroll bar to window, which is top level container.

Comment: I add the scroll bar to a container.

Answer (score 1):

Good question. Clicking on arrows isn't handled by `ScrollBar`, it's handled by `ScrollBarUI`. I believe that default implementation(or at least base class for majority of `ScrollBarUI` implementations) is `BasicScrollBarUI`.

If you'll take a look into source of `javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicScrollBarUI` it has `incrButton` and `decrButton` buttons and they are components you want listen to.

P.S. I had similar need for having custom (key) listener for my `Slider` and having custom ui which exposes needed components/model(as you could see almost all components are protected so you easy could access them in subclasses and expose via public getters) worked great for me. I did that in plain java though, maybe in scala you can listen to buttons just by specyfying property name.

Answer (score 0):

One more piece of Scala Swing being broken. The `Adjustable` trait seems to be completely hollow, nothing is wired.

The following works:

```
class ScrollBarAlive extends swing.ScrollBar {
  me =>
  peer.addAdjustmentListener(new java.awt.event.AdjustmentListener {
    def adjustmentValueChanged(e: java.awt.event.AdjustmentEvent) {
      publish(new swing.event.ValueChanged(me))
    }
  })
}
```

Test:

```
import swing._

object ScrollBarTest extends SimpleSwingApplication {
  lazy val top = new Frame {
    val label   = new Label { text = "0" }
    val scroll  = new ScrollBarAlive {
      orientation = Orientation.Horizontal
      listenTo(this)
      reactions += {
        case event.ValueChanged(_) =>
          label.text = value.toString + (if (valueIsAjusting) " A" else "")
      }
    }
    contents = new BorderPanel {
      add(label,  BorderPanel.Position.North)
      add(scroll, BorderPanel.Position.South)
    }
    pack().centerOnScreen()
    open()
  }
}
```

A proper implementation would also introduce a subtype of `AdjustingEvent`.